# Do table slices take up memory in R?

Tags: r, memory-management, premature-optimization, optimization

If I take a slice of a table using, say the column names, does R allocate memory to hold the slice in a new location? Specifically, I have a table with columns depth1 and depth2, among others. I want to add columns which contain the max and min of the two. I have 2 approaches:

```
dd = dat[,c("depth1","depth2")]
dat$mindepth = apply(dd,1,min)
dat$maxdepth = apply(dd,1,max)
remove(dd)
```

or

```
dat$mindepth = apply(dat[,c("depth1","depth2")],1,min)
dat$maxdepth = apply(dat[,c("depth1","depth2")],1,max)
```

If I am not using up new memory, I'd rather take the slice only once, otherwise I would like save the reallocation. Which one is better? Memory issues can be critical when dealing with large datasets so please don't downvote this with the root of all evil meme.

Comment: Subsetting pretty much anything in R creates a copy.  There are a few exceptions in contributed packages.

Comment: @hadley - do you want to post that as an answer, so it can be accepted etc just for the records...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this doesn't *actually* answer the main thrust of the question (@hadley has done that and deserves credit), but there are other options to those you suggest. Here you could use `pmin()` and `pmax()` as another solution, and using `with()` or `within()` we can do it without explicit subsetting to create a `dd`.

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(depth1 = runif(10), depth2 = runif(10))
R> dat <- within(dat, mindepth <- pmin(depth1, depth2))
R> dat <- within(dat, maxdepth <- pmax(depth1, depth2))
R> 
R> dat
       depth1    depth2   mindepth  maxdepth
1  0.26550866 0.2059746 0.20597457 0.2655087
2  0.37212390 0.1765568 0.17655675 0.3721239
3  0.57285336 0.6870228 0.57285336 0.6870228
4  0.90820779 0.3841037 0.38410372 0.9082078
5  0.20168193 0.7698414 0.20168193 0.7698414
6  0.89838968 0.4976992 0.49769924 0.8983897
7  0.94467527 0.7176185 0.71761851 0.9446753
8  0.66079779 0.9919061 0.66079779 0.9919061
9  0.62911404 0.3800352 0.38003518 0.6291140
10 0.06178627 0.7774452 0.06178627 0.7774452
```

We can look at how much copying goes on with `tracemem()` but **only** if your R was compiled with the following configure option activated `--enable-memory-profiling`.

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(depth1 = runif(10), depth2 = runif(10))
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x2641cd8>"
R> dat <- within(dat, mindepth <- pmin(depth1, depth2))
tracemem[0x2641cd8 -> 0x2641a00]: within.data.frame within 
tracemem[0x2641a00 -> 0x2641878]: [<-.data.frame [<- within.data.frame within 
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x2657bc8>"
R> dat <- within(dat, maxdepth <- pmax(depth1, depth2))
tracemem[0x2657bc8 -> 0x2c765d8]: within.data.frame within 
tracemem[0x2c765d8 -> 0x2c764b8]: [<-.data.frame [<- within.data.frame within
```

So we see that R copied `dat` twice during each `within()` call. Compare that with your two suggestions:

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(depth1 = runif(10), depth2 = runif(10))
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x2e1ddd0>"
R> dd <- dat[,c("depth1","depth2")]
R> tracemem(dd)
[1] "<0x2df01a0>"
R> dat$mindepth = apply(dd,1,min)
tracemem[0x2df01a0 -> 0x2cf97d8]: as.matrix.data.frame as.matrix apply 
tracemem[0x2e1ddd0 -> 0x2cc0ab0]: 
tracemem[0x2cc0ab0 -> 0x2cc0b20]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x2cc0b20 -> 0x2cc0bc8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x26b93c8>"
R> dat$maxdepth = apply(dd,1,max)
tracemem[0x2df01a0 -> 0x2cc0e30]: as.matrix.data.frame as.matrix apply 
tracemem[0x26b93c8 -> 0x26742c8]: 
tracemem[0x26742c8 -> 0x2674358]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x2674358 -> 0x2674478]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

Here, `dd` is copied once in each call to `apply` because `apply()` converts `dd` to a matrix before proceeding. The final three lines in the each block of `tracemem` output indicates three copies of `dat` are being made to insert the new column.

What about your second option?

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(depth1 = runif(10), depth2 = runif(10))
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x268bc88>"
R> dat$mindepth <- apply(dat[,c("depth1","depth2")],1,min)
tracemem[0x268bc88 -> 0x26376b0]: 
tracemem[0x26376b0 -> 0x2637720]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x2637720 -> 0x2637790]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x2466d40>"
R> dat$maxdepth <- apply(dat[,c("depth1","depth2")],1,max)
tracemem[0x2466d40 -> 0x22ae0d8]: 
tracemem[0x22ae0d8 -> 0x22ae1f8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x22ae1f8 -> 0x22ae318]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

Here this version avoids the copy involved in setting up `dd`, but in all other respects is similar to your previous suggestion.

Can we do any better? Yes, and one simple way is to use the `within()` option I started with but execute both statements to create new `mindepth` and `maxdepth` variables in the one call to `within()`:

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(depth1 = runif(10), depth2 = runif(10))
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x21c4158>"
R> dat <- within(dat, { mindepth <- pmin(depth1, depth2)
+                      maxdepth <- pmax(depth1, depth2) })
tracemem[0x21c4158 -> 0x21c44a0]: within.data.frame within 
tracemem[0x21c44a0 -> 0x21c4628]: [<-.data.frame [<- within.data.frame within
```

In this version we only invoke two copies of `dat` compared to the 4 copies of the original `within()` version.

What about if we coerce `dat` to a matrix and then do the insertions?

```
R> set.seed(1)
R> dat <- data.frame(depth1 = runif(10), depth2 = runif(10))
R> tracemem(dat)
[1] "<0x1f29c70>"
R> mat <- as.matrix.data.frame(dat)
tracemem[0x1f29c70 -> 0x1f09768]: as.matrix.data.frame 
R> tracemem(mat)
[1] "<0x245ff30>"
R> mat <- cbind(mat, pmin(mat[,1], mat[,2]), pmax(mat[,1], mat[,2]))
R>
```

That is an improvement as we only incur the cost of the single copy of `dat` when coercing to a matrix. I cheated a bit by calling the `as.matrix.data.frame()` method directly. If we'd just used `as.matrix()` we'd have incurred another copy of `mat`.

This highlights one of the reasons why matrices are so much faster to use than data frames.